# How to keep lines which contains specific string and remove other lines from .txt file?

Tags: python, file, txt

How to keep lines which contains specific string and remove other lines from .txt file?

Example: I want to keep the line which has word "hey" and remove others.

test.txt file:

```
first line

second one

heyy yo yo

fourth line
```

Code:

```
keeplist = ["hey"]
with open("test.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in keeplist:
```

Comment: The `in` operator will be useful for you

Comment: `if word in line: print(line)` now you just need to write to a file instead of printing

Comment: this should be the result?

```keeplist = ["hey"]
with open("test.txt", "r+") as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in keeplist:
            if word in line:
                f.writelines(line)```

Comment: like this you are writing to the old file `f` without deleting what comes before

Comment: In your example, is "heyy yo yo" included because it contains the string "hey", or excluded because its not the _word_ "hey"?

Comment: @tdelaney it's included because it contains string "hey"

Comment: i think it should be this then
```with open("test.txt", "r+") as f:
    for line in f:
            if line.__contains__("hey"):
                f.truncate(0)
                f.writelines(line)
                f.close()```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its hard to remove lines from a file. Its usually better to write a temporary file with the desired content and then change that to the original file name.

```
import os

keeplist = ["hey"]
with open("test.txt") as f, open("test.txt.tmp", "w") as outf:
    for line in f:
        for word in keeplist:
            if word in line:
                outf.write(line)
                break
os.rename("test.txt.tmp", "test.txt")
```